# Tomcat 8 jars are not showing up on server tab

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

[image]

I have imported all the jar files required for my spring web application in build path as well as in lib folder(under webcontent folder). But not showing up in server tab once the project added to server to run. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? All jars need to be shown there and I'm not able to run the application because of this.

Comment: what exception are you getting ?

Comment: if possible you should consider using a Maven or Gradle they make our life much easier.

Comment: perform deployment assembly through eclipse. right click on project-> build path->configur build path->deployment assembly->add->java buildpath entries, select jars and click ok

Comment: I did that, still not working.

Comment: I'm getting error 404, no exception on console what so ever. No, I built web apps without maven, so dont think its an issue with that..

Comment: if possible post your code snippet, with `xml` files

Comment: Check here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rahulrajcse/6m1eujbq/






    I have added index.jsp in both root directory as well as in /web-inf/jsp/
It should appear anyways, but not appearing, getting tomcat 404 error in browser, no error in console

Comment: In my project, also also don't see all jars listed there... don't really know what this means anyway. The importat thing is that you properly configure your deployment assembly

Comment: There's something weird about tomcat 8/ java 1.8
I have tested with three different apps, atleast one is confirmed running successfully in other environments, but failed in this scenario. Dont really know why not able to detect jsp files to load up.

Comment: *"and I'm not able to run the application because of this."* wrong assumption. I suggest to step back and ask how to solve a real problem instead of how to solve an assumed problem.

Comment: If I know the real problem, I would have not posted here, I Would have solved it myself. So if you dont get a solution or cant help me out or not interested, then do me a favor please do not comment..